# how can we pass data from crystal report(8.5) to vb form

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-8.5

I made Invoice By Crystal Report v8.5 (Vb6 & Access). There is item Name and Price. At last Net Payable Amount:500(Exp), I need to Show In words(Five hundred). Crystal built in  Function is not appropiate for it. So write a function in VB6 and it works nice. Now problem is how i send this value Crystal Report (v8.5) to vb.(I know  to send data From VB6 to Crystal)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an easy way to accomplish a number to words conversion using Crystal Formula syntax.

Since you already have a working function in VB6 that does what you need, you may wish to create your own custom function library for Crystal Reports.  The following tutorial walks you through creating a Crystal UFL COM DLL:

[Creating a Crystal Reports Custom Function Library](http://www.slxdeveloper.com/page.aspx?action=viewarticle&articleid=103)

Crystal Reports 8.5 does support Basic syntax, so you could also try porting your function to CR's flavor of VB. [(Source, see page 412)](http://discovernd.com/cnd/c85/UserGde.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the function in Crystal Reports. If you choose to use the vb syntax, it will be pretty similar to the one you already wrote.